# unfortunately the application has stopped

Tags: android

when i start my activity in the emulator of eclipse i have the message

> unfortunately the application has stopped

I do not understand the LogCat my logCat says that please help me i am starting loosing hope .

```
04-24 15:52:19.729: W/Trace(982): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-24 15:52:19.729: W/Trace(982): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-24 15:52:20.599: D/dalvikvm(982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 8% free 2567K/2788K, paused 60ms, total 63ms
04-24 15:52:20.609: I/dalvikvm-heap(982): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.225MB for 614416-byte allocation
04-24 15:52:20.679: D/dalvikvm(982): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3165K/3392K, paused 65ms, total 66ms
04-24 15:52:20.789: D/dalvikvm(982): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 3165K/3392K, paused 32ms+16ms, total 114ms
04-24 15:52:20.989: D/dalvikvm(982): GC_CONCURRENT freed 674K, 24% free 2906K/3792K, paused 25ms+24ms, total 114ms
04-24 15:52:21.049: D/AndroidRuntime(982): Shutting down VM
04-24 15:52:21.061: W/dalvikvm(982): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {tabet.salah.ventemagasin/tabet.salah.ventemagasin.LoginActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please learn to read logcat. `LoginActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()` it tells you exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {tabet.salah.ventemagasin/tabet.salah.ventemagasin.LoginActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()

call `super.onCreate(savedinstancestate)` in your LoginActivity `onCreate()` method

Comment: it works thinks 
but how you can read the LogCat and searche the error please

Comment: It is so simple, just look logcat once, you will find Exception along with cause i.e it starts like `caused by ....` , that will show the root cause

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your `onCreate()`

```
super.onCreate()
```

Comment: thinks a lot how you read the log cat and searche the error please

Comment: The first line of the stack trace is:
04-24 15:52:21.069: E/AndroidRuntime(982): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {tabet.salah.ventemagasin/tabet.salah.ventemagasin.LoginActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()

Answer (score 3):

in your activity `LoginActivity` in `onCreate` add:

```
super.onCreate();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not calling `super.onCreate()` in your `LoginActivity`'s `onCreate`